# How to add variable to array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode3.2

I have the code 
    [usrs addObject:usrString]
I am trying to make it so that the program adds whatever the string usrString is to the array every time that you press a button, and that the string is different every time. However, whenever I run this code, it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even add an object to the array. How can I make this code do what I want?

Comment: Are you using an NSMutableArray? Irrespective, we need to see the code. Also, where are you expecting the string data to come from?

Comment: I think this may be a rephrase of middaparka's question: have you actually created an array, or merely declared a pointer to one in your class? All objects have to be explicitly created in Objective-C.

Comment: I have declared the variable previously, it is a mutable array, and the string data comes from the input from a textbox, which I convert into a string.

Comment: Sorry I meant array. I have declared the array earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take a shot in the dark and say that you forgot to alloc/init your `NSMutableArray`.  In Objective-C, sending messages to `nil` will fail silently.

e.x.

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: This solved part of my problem thanks! However, I still would like to know how to make it add whatever string the user inputs. Thanks again!